# How to make a many-to-many relationship act like a foreign key relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to get a TabularInline working with a many-to-many relationship, but I can only get the relationship object to display. It works fine if I use a foreign key relationship.

So let's say this is my many-to-many relationship:

```
# Jobs have many workers, and workers can be assigned to many jobs

class Job(models.Model):
    workers = models.ManyToManyField(Worker, related_name='jobs')

class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # workers relationships with other models
    insurance = models.ForeignKey(Insurance, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

This doesn't play nicely with a TabularInline as it will only display the Job_Worker object.

So I'm wondering is there some way to make the relationship seem like a foreign key relationship? For example, worker gets a foreign key to an intermediate table, and "through" is used. The end result being it "works out of the box" for a TabularInline.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do it using stock Django tools. And it is for good. It prevents you from modifying the related object on another end of many-to-many, that could be in fact used by other instances.

If you feel desperate and must do it exactly like you describe, your only way is to create custom forms for your inline admin. It is [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form), too.